# How to limit the amount of numbers given in a float input? (Python)

Tags: python, input, numbers, limit

Novice Pythoner here. I am trying to finish my first program (a tip calculator) and I have one last piece of code to write. Here is the part of code I need to add on to:

```
bill_amt = True
while bill_amt:
    try:
        bill_amt = float(input('First, what was the price of your meal?:'))
    except:
        print('Please enter a number only.')
        continue
    if bill_amt <= 0:
        print('Your meal wasn\'t $',bill_amt,'! Please try again.')
        bill_amt = True
    else:
        x = float(bill_amt)
        bill_amt = False
```

What I want to do is add a command that will limit the amount of numbers you can input when the code asks how much your meal was so user can't type in 4511511513545513513518451.32. I've tried using len(bill_amt) > 8, but I get an error that floats don't have strings. How do I get around this? Thanks, sorry if it's a duplicate! -Pottsy

Comment: should `except ValueError:` not just `except`

Comment: `if bill_amt > 99999.99:`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe 0.00000000000000000000000001 > 99999999 evaluates to False

Answer (score 1):

use regex matching, this will also prevent the user from typing in something like `"12.123456"`

```
import re
# ...

while True:
    inp = input('First, what was the price of your meal?:'))
    if bool(re.match(r"^\d{1,8}\.\d\d$", inp)):
        return float(inp)
    else:
        print('invalid entry')
```

`\d` means digit, `{1,8}` means allow anywhere from 1 to 8 digits.  `\d\d` looks for two digits after the `.`, so this regex will match 1-8 digits, followed by a dot, followed by two more digits.

Note that if you are dealing with money, you don't generally want to use floats, but rather `decimal.Decimal`s.  Try doing

```
decimal.Decimal(inp)
```

at the end instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Float` doesn't have length but `str` does:

```
bill_amt_str = input('First, what was the price of your meal?:')
if len(bill_amt_str.replace(".", "")) > 8:
    print("No more than 8 digits please.")
    continue
bill_amt = float(bill_amt_str)
```

Comment: Or, use in-place conversion without adding extra variable; having bill_amt as it was, just check  `if len(str(bill_amt))>8:`

Comment: @GMGray garbage collector will wipe out this tiny little string anyway.

Comment: @GMGray there's an extra name but no more space allocated for the variable

Comment: @Ryan Haining - of course, it's just a matter of personal coding preferences.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo - could you explain where are potential problems with this shortcut? I'd have to get rid of bad habits then..

Comment: @GMGray you'd have to account for the conversion to float failing, the omission of the intermediate name would impact the overall appearance of this but I wouldn't call it a problem

Comment: @GMGray I've removed the part about bad practice - I misunderstood you. Your snippet is OK in general. But in the case of OP's code, plese notice that value returned by `input()` is already a string and then it's converted to float. Basically I'm using the original value to count digits and this way I'm avoiding double conversion - `str -> float -> str`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the length use str(bill_amount)

len(str(123.53)) is 6

Note that even though Python will allow you to use a float value and then change it to the boolean, it would be better to make it a different name rather than have both the float and the boolean as bill_amt
.